# Java Thread Hanging

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, numbers, flags

I am writing simple multithreaded code that has 2 threads. One prints out even numbers between 0 and 500 and the other prints odd numbers between 1 and 500. I want the numbers to print out in order though by changing how threads interact with each other. It works well, but the threads hang at the end for some reason...even when I return from the run()...

Also, am I using flags correctly or is there a better way?

```
public class Multithreading {
    public static Even even;
    public static Odd odd;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        even = new Even();
        odd = new Odd();

        Thread a = new Thread(even);
        Thread b = new Thread(odd);
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }

    public static class Odd implements Runnable {

        public boolean running;

        public void run() {
            odd.pauseThread();
            while (!running) {}
            for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i += 2) {
                System.out.println(i);

                odd.pauseThread();

                while (!running) {
                    even.resumeThread();

                    if (i > 500) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void pauseThread() {
            running = false;
        }

        public void resumeThread() {
            running = true;
        }
    }

    public static class Even implements Runnable {

        public boolean running;

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i += 2) {
                System.out.println(i);
                even.pauseThread();

                while (!running) {
                    odd.resumeThread();

                    if (i > 500) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void pauseThread() {
            running = false;
        }

        public void resumeThread() {
            running = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the hang, are you sure it "works well"?  Your flags are not properly synchronized, which should cause the program to behave unexpectedly.  I would guess that you get inconsistent results printed out every time you run it.  Am I right?

Comment: "Ouch! The tight loop, it hurts!"

Answer (score 1):

As you'll soon learn, multi-threaded programming is very difficult and requires a very good understanding of how threads interact with memory and with each other.

From your program, I can tell that you need to invest more time into learning the basics of concurrent programming.

The main issues that I can see:

- static global and unsynchronized use of `even` and `odd` instances.
- unsynchronized use of the `running` variables.
- When it's not a thread's turn to write a number, it waits by doing a very CPU-intensive tight loop.
- Your thread exit condition can never happen: `if (i > 500) {`

That last point is sure to cause at least one of the threads never to exit, thus producing the "hang".  But I'm sure that the other points are causing race conditions as well, and may be contributing factors.

I ran your program, and I found that, besides the "hang", I never actually got the correct results printed out, and very often, got inconsistent results as well.

Here is a working program that attempts to follow your general design, while fixing the problems above.  It will be your homework to read about how this works.

```
public class Multithreading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SharedData sharedData = new SharedData();
        Even even = new Even(sharedData);
        Odd odd = new Odd(sharedData);

        Thread a = new Thread(even);
        Thread b = new Thread(odd);

        a.start();
        b.start();
    }

    private static class SharedData {
        public final Object syncObject = new Object();
        public boolean evensTurn = true;
    }

    private static class Odd implements Runnable {

        private final SharedData sharedData;

        public Odd(SharedData sharedData) {
            this.sharedData = sharedData;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i += 2) {
                synchronized (this.sharedData.syncObject) {
                    while (this.sharedData.evensTurn) {
                        try {
                            this.sharedData.syncObject.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println(i);
                    this.sharedData.evensTurn = true;
                    this.sharedData.syncObject.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Even implements Runnable {

        private final SharedData sharedData;

        public Even(SharedData sharedData) {
            this.sharedData = sharedData;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i += 2) {
                synchronized (this.sharedData.syncObject) {
                    while (!this.sharedData.evensTurn) {
                        try {
                            this.sharedData.syncObject.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println(i);
                    this.sharedData.evensTurn = false;
                    this.sharedData.syncObject.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Recommended reading: [The entire Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: For someone recommending that someone else read the entire Java Concurrency Tutorial, I'm surprised by the lack of more advanced concurrency constructs that Java offers in your response.

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue is one of the best options to address this issue.

Comment: Well, I guess it's a compliment that no one is questioning the correctness of the code I posted :)  I don't doubt that there are different ways to address OP's problem. Feel free to post an alternate answer for everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like Producer/Consumer problem.
Please check the below link
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813407/Producer-Consumer-Problem

Just user wait and notify for thread communication.